# Positioning Text and an Image with CSS and HTML

Tags: css, text-formatting

Hi there I'm currently making a simple website to get more experience with HTML and CSS currently I' having a simple problem with placement in my header. I am trying to get a logo and text to be in a specific location but am unaware of how to achieve it affectively with my skills in CSS. Basically I have this currently:

[image: Current Version]

This is what I'd like to have for text formatting with the logo:
[image: Photoshop version]

I am unsure of how to get this formatted in CSS and have been looking up information on W3 schools for information and have learned quite a but but not enough to figure this out sadly. I can figure out the color styling that will match the desired version but I cannot figure out how to get the text and logo to be located where they should be.

Here is the CSS and HTML I have so far (very basic):

```css
#header {
    background-color:#011836;
    color:#ECE7E7;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: .1px;
}
.logo{
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top:5px;
    bottom:0px;
}
.headerText{
    text-indent: 160px;
    bottom:20px;
    font-family: "Verdana";
  
}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#179fe8;
    color:white;
    height:50px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.button{
    background-color: #179fe8;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button2:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
#section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
#footer {
    background-color:#011836;
    color:white;
    font-family: "Verdana";
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">

    <img class="logo" src="http://imgur.com/O2qNi6p" alt="Clarence White Logo" width="168" height="168">

    <h1 class="headerText" style= "display:inline;">BIOENGINEERING CLUB </h1>
    <h5 class="headerText">UNIVERSITY OF MAINE</h5>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<button href="about.html" class="button button2">ABOUT</button>
<button href="projects.html" class="button button2">PROJECTS</button>
<button href="resume.html" class="button button2">RESUME</button>
</div>

<div id="section">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
<p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any guidance on how to better achieve the styling would be very appreciated! Please be patient with me I'm learning this all over again and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```css
#header {
  background-color:#011836;
  color:#ECE7E7;
  padding: 5px;
  position:relative;             /* ADDED */
}
#header:after{                   /* ADDED */
  content:"";
  display: table;
  clear:both;
}
.headerText{                     /* CHANGED */
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:200px;
}
.logo{
  position: relative;
  float:left;                    /* ADDED */
  left: 5px;
  top:5px;
}

#nav {
  line-height:30px;
  background-color:#179fe8;
  color:white;
  height:50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.button{
  background-color: #179fe8;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 4px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button2:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
#section {
  width:350px;
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
}
#footer {
  background-color:#011836;
  color:white;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  clear:both;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="header">

      <img class="logo" src="http://imgur.com/O2qNi6p" alt="Clarence White Logo" width="168" height="168">
      <div class="headerText"> <!-- CREATED AN ABSOLUTE POS. PARENT -->
        <h1>BIOENGINEERING CLUB </h1>
        <h5>UNIVERSITY OF MAINE</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
      <button href="about.html" class="button button2">ABOUT</button>
      <button href="projects.html" class="button button2">PROJECTS</button>
      <button href="resume.html" class="button button2">RESUME</button>
    </div>

    <div id="section">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
        with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
      <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
        its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you that does make sense that the positions would be relative! I appreciate your help have a good day!